# Getting files from a directory and adding them to a zip file

Tags: php, arrays, file, directory, zip

I've created a zip file named 'files.zip'. I have images inside my property_image folder. I've scanned that directory and have the type of files I need. '$prop_image' is another array which have the names of images. If an image file(which is in the variable '$file1') is in that array then I'm trying add the file into zip file.

```
        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $filename = "files.zip";

        if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
            exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
        }

        $dir = './property_image';
        $file1 = scandir($dir);
        foreach($file1 as $feel){
            $userfile_extn = substr($feel, strrpos($feel, '.')+1);
            if($userfile_extn === 'jpg' || $userfile_extn === 'png' || $userfile_extn === 'gif' || $userfile_extn === 'jpeg'){
                if(in_array($feel, $prop_image)){

                    $zip->addFile("$feel", basename($feel));
                }

            } // end of if($extension ===
        }

        $zip->addFile("$File", basename($File));
        $zip->close();
```

This code only adds '$File' into that zip file if I comment out the code:

```
$zip->addFile("$feel", basename($feel));
```

I need to add those files from that directory which are inside the variable '$prop_image' in the zip file.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

It might be helpful to someone else so, I'm posting my answer. That was easy. I only need to give the folder name in which the images are saved.

Like this::

```
$zip->addFile("./property_image/$feel", basename($feel));
```

in place of::

```
$zip->addFile("$feel", basename($feel));
```